# What's the best way to implement recurring events db model

Tags: php, calendar

Currently we have system where event metadata (weekly, yearly, daily) is stored in one table and all the instances of recurring event in another table.

Now we have additional requirement to add events with any generic events that can be created, for example

few patterns:
2nd day of every 3rd week in a month.
every 3 rd year
every 3 days
etc...etc..

What is the best model which can cover all these possibilities, i have gone through few thread where its said that cron pattern will be suitable.

Would like to know your opinion before i move ahead with this approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check sqcrm.com where I have implemented the recurring events.You can download source code for the implementation. In addition you may check vtiger crm they also have done recurrent events. In sqcrm I have created a new event for each recurrent date but I suppose in Vtiger its not the same way.

Comment: thanks Abhik, i see below ddl in sqcrm CREATE TABLE `recurrent_events` (
  `idrecurrent_events` int(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idevents` int(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recurrent_pattern` text <-- what is the format you are using here

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this field will store a JSON string. The reason I used this is when I visit the parent event I need to show the recurring pattern and the pattern is shown here. But the nonrecurring payments will be stored in the events table just like other but will have a parent id.

Comment: "But the nonrecurring payments"  should be * But the recurring events..

Comment: what is the pattern you are storing, is it something like 'yearly##every2year##date' or similar

Comment: No its something like recurrent_pattern: {"recurrent_options":1,"repeat_end_opts":1,"repeat_end_num_occurence":10,"repeat_end_date":"","repeat_freq_opts":1,"weekly_opts":[],"repeat_monthly_opts":"","repeat_monthly_opts_days":"","repeat_monthly_opts_week_freq":"","repeat_monthly_opts_week_weekdays":""}

The above pattern is same as that in the recurrent setting option, i.e. "recurrent_options":1 means recurrent is set , "repeat_end_opts":1 means a number "repeat_end_num_occurence":10 means after 10 occurrence and so on.These will store html element and val and used in edit form.

Comment: Thanks much for the info, with the above json can you store below scenario 'every 1st Monday of the month' or 'every thursday of third week in month'

Comment: Yes for the first case its going to be {"recurrent_options":6,"repeat_end_opts":1,"repeat_end_num_occurence":10,"repeat_end_date":"","repeat_freq_opts":1,"weekly_opts":[],"repeat_monthly_opts":2,"repeat_monthly_opts_days":"","repeat_monthly_opts_week_freq":"first","repeat_monthly_opts_week_weekdays":"monday"}
You may check the HTML part with the element being used and the values. "recurrent_options":6 means monthly. Check the HTML you will come to know its easy. The only difficult part is date calculation which u can see in modules/Calendar/Recurrentevents.class.php